# Geometry Nodes: Instance on Points

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to figure out how Instance Index on Instance on Points works. I have an example here: [image: Blender 3.4 screen shot]

Currently, instance index is fed by a Random Value node, which gives me random selections from a collection of cube, star, and torus objects, on the tips of 3 cones. What I would like is to feed instance index with a sequence, so that one each of the Toppers collection is chosen per cone.

Whatever choice I make to feed instance index, besides random value, gives the same item on each cone. I could fix this by using multiple instance on points nodes, but my hope is to use this setup without a limit on the Toppers collection. Also, I want to know why random value is the only node (so far) that can produce differing instances on the cones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood completely what you are trying to accomplish, so I don’t know if this setup will satisfy your necessity.

[image]

The limitation that I found is that you need the same number of *point* to instance and *objects* in the collection, otherwise you will start to have duplicates.

Comment: This answers the question fully.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

did you try this?

This gives you all parts...again and again.

I think what is a bit confusing here, that although there is no value plugged into "instance index", internally they plug in 0,1,2,0,1,2... and so on if you have 3 instances.
But Blender does this pretty often. E.g. in texture nodes.

Comment: The root of my problem, I think, is that I was using "Selection" to isolate the vertices needed. When that's disconnected, I had instances blooming all over the cones.